# I am trying to hide and show partial templates with radio buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a client that wants to offer 4 different membership types and allow people to pay for each with either a credit card or PayPal. I created donation pages for each type of membership and payment method. I have to do that to tag each new member with their membership type and assign a tracking code.

I have created a radio button for each membership type and when a user clicks on a particular button, the appropriate donation form displays.

The html is:

```
     <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="member-button">
   <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="weekly"> <h3>Weekly</h3></label>
     <h4>$1.00 per week</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="member-button">
         <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="monthly"> <h3>Monthly</h3></label>  
         <h4>$19.95 per month</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="member-button">
         <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="annual"> <h3>Annual</h3></label> 
         <h4>$25.00 per year</h4>
       </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="member-button">
         <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="lifetime"> <h3>Lifetime</h3></label> 
         <h4>$999.00 for life</h4>
       </div> 
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">   
    <div class="weekly box">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="donate-wrap-left">
      {% subpage "weekly" with "donation_partial" %}
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="donate-wrap-right">
      {% subpage "weekly_paypal" with "donation_partial" %}
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="monthly box">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="donate-wrap-left">
      {% subpage "monthly" with "donation_partial" %}
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="donate-wrap-right">
      {% subpage "monthly_paypal" with "donation_partial" %}
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="annual box">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="donate-wrap-left">
      {% subpage "one_time" with "donation_partial" %}
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="donate-wrap-right">
      {% subpage "one_time_paypal" with "donation_partial" %}
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div id="lifetime box">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="donate-wrap-left">
      {% subpage "one_time_999" with "donation_partial" %}
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="donate-wrap-right">
      {% subpage "lifetime_paypal" with "donation_partial" %}
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="weekly"){
            $(".box").not(".weekly").hide();
            $(".weekly").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="monthly"){
            $(".box").not(".monthly").hide();
            $(".monthly").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="annual"){
            $(".box").not(".annual").hide();
            $(".annual").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="lifetime"){
            $(".box").not(".lifetime").hide();
            $(".lifetime").show();
        }
     });
    });
</script>
```

The script basically works but I am having 2 issues. First, even though on page load none of the radio buttons are checked all the donate forms are visible. Second, when I click on weekly, monthly or annual, the lifetime donation forms remain visible.

Ideally I would like the Weekly radio button to be checked by default and only that form display and obviously I'd like to find out how to hide the lifetime forms unless that radio button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

First put a `checked` attribute in the default `input`

```
    <input type="radio" value="weekly" name="member" checked="checked" />
```

Then follow the DRY principle, Don't repeat your self..

Create function, which handles hiding and showing based on the type

```
function showOnlyForType(type) {
   var className = "." + type;
   $(".box").not(className).hide();
   $(className).show();
}
```

Do you already see, how your life gets easier?

If no, here an example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // call it to show only weekly type when ready
    showOnlyForType('weekly');

    // handle event..
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
      showOnlyForType(this.val())
    });
});
```

Comment: @charlietfl Of course, it's just an example, I'll edit cheers

Comment: @webdeb Thanks for the tip on the DRY principle. As you can probably tell, I am not yet at the point where I am remembering javascript principles. I have to learn some first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have some errors in the HTML code itself, is everything there nested correctly, like you intend it to...? Here's my approach :

```js
function setDonation(radio){
  var donations = ['weeklybox','monthlybox','annualbox','lifetimebox'];
  for(var i=0;i<donations.length;i++)
   document.getElementById(donations[i]).style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById(radio.value+'box').style.display = 'block';
 }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="member-button">
   <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="weekly" checked onclick="setDonation(this);"> <h3>Weekly</h3></label>
     <h4>$1.00 per week</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="member-button">
         <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="monthly" onclick="setDonation(this);"> <h3>Monthly</h3></label>  
         <h4>$19.95 per month</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="member-button">
         <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="annual" onclick="setDonation(this);"> <h3>Annual</h3></label> 
         <h4>$25.00 per year</h4>
       </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="member-button">
         <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="lifetime" onclick="setDonation(this);"> <h3>Lifetime</h3></label> 
         <h4>$999.00 for life</h4>
       </div> 
  </div>
  </div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="weekly box" id="weeklybox">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="donate-wrap-left">
    {% subpage "weekly" with "donation_partial" %}
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="donate-wrap-right">
    {% subpage "weekly_paypal" with "donation_partial" %}
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="monthly box" id="monthlybox" style="display:none;">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="donate-wrap-left">
    {% subpage "monthly" with "donation_partial" %}
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="donate-wrap-right">
    {% subpage "monthly_paypal" with "donation_partial" %}
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="annual box" id="annualbox" style="display:none;">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="donate-wrap-left">
    {% subpage "one_time" with "donation_partial" %}
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="donate-wrap-right">
    {% subpage "one_time_paypal" with "donation_partial" %}
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="lifetime box" id="lifetimebox" style="display:none;">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="donate-wrap-left">
    {% subpage "one_time_999" with "donation_partial" %}
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="donate-wrap-right">
    {% subpage "lifetime_paypal" with "donation_partial" %}
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main points here :**

Add IDs to all donation sections and hide all but the first section with display:none. The rest is done by the setDonation() function - I also assigned that function to those radios directly in HTML instead of by code, probably a matter of personal taste - but I would still recommend this, keeps everything cleaner and easier to read if you return to the code after some time.

Comment: Thanks @ElDoRado1239. That worked really well and is almost exactly what I was looking for. Really appreciate it.